# What happens behind the scenes when we build loadable kernel modules

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, makefile, kernel-module

I have built few kernel modules before and I followed the steps to generate the .ko files to insmod.

I write a Makefile which has

```
obj-m := filename.o
```

and execute the command from shell

```
# make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=`pwd` modules
```

This command generates the filename.ko, filename.mod, filename.o, filename.mod.o.

Some google search showed that /lib/modules/$()/build is a symbolic link to my kernel source tree.
and `M=pwd` is my source file directory.

But what happens when just this small piece of command executes to generate my .ko kernel object file. Where, which directories, or binaries, utilities will the make command use.

PS: ( the filename.ko file would be generated by some compilation magic using filename.o and filename.mod.o ).

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the makefile in `/lib/modules/$()/build`

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/

Comment: Can you please summarize those txt files in that directory. At least some keywords to look for. I cannot link it with anything I have done till now, ( apparently I have done very little).

Comment: Read https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Comment: @erdag `modules.txt` has some details on the Makefile syntax and how to build external modules for running Kernel or other Kernel trees. You may also have a look on `makefiles.txt`. The rest (`kbuild.` and `kconfigXXX`) is for kbuild (the kernel build system).

Comment: Run `make -v` it will show everything which it does.